# How to maintain ngrams in a quanteda dfm?

Tags: r, n-gram, quanteda

I'm using quanteda to create a document feature matrix (dfm) from a tokens object. My tokens object contains many ngrams (ex: "united_states"). When I create a dfm using the dfm() function, my ngrams are split by the understcore ("united_states" gets split into "united" "states"). How can I create a dfm while maintaining my ngrams?

Here's my process:

```
my_tokens <- tokens(my_corpus, remove_symbols=TRUE, remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE)
my_tokens <- tokens_compound(pattern=phrase(my_ngrams))
my_dfm <- dfm(my_tokens, stem= FALSE, tolower=TRUE)
```

I see "united_states" in my_tokens, but in the dfm it becomes "united" and "states" as separate tokens.

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear which version of **quanteda** you are using, but basically this should work, since the default tokenizer (from `tokens()`) will not split words containing an inner `_`.

Demonstration:

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 2.1.1

# tokens() will not separate _ words
tokens("united_states")
## Tokens consisting of 1 document.
## text1 :
## [1] "united_states"
```

Here's a reproducible example for the phrase "United States":

```r
my_corpus <- tail(data_corpus_inaugural, 3)

# show that the phrase exists
head(kwic(my_corpus, phrase("united states"), window = 2))
##                                                                  
##  [2009-Obama, 2685:2686]   bless the | United States | of America
##      [2013-Obama, 13:14]      of the | United States | Congress, 
##  [2013-Obama, 2313:2314] bless these | United States | of America
##    [2017-Trump, 347:348]       , the | United States | of America
##  [2017-Trump, 1143:1144]      to the | United States | of America

my_tokens <- tokens(my_corpus,
  remove_symbols = TRUE,
  remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE
)
my_tokens <- tokens_compound(my_tokens, pattern = phrase("united states"))
my_dfm <- dfm(my_tokens, stem = FALSE, tolower = TRUE)

dfm_select(my_dfm, "*_*")
## Document-feature matrix of: 3 documents, 1 feature (0.0% sparse) and 4 docvars.
##             features
## docs         united_states
##   2009-Obama             1
##   2013-Obama             2
##   2017-Trump             2
```